# Magento add altered image to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I have a product with an upload file custom option. The accepted file is an image. After the image is uploaded, i have a javascript function that edits the image and generates a base64 string image. The issue now is I do not want magento to add the originally uploaded image to the cart, but the new base64 string image. I've tried manipulating the original uploaded file using javascript but the file api is not mutable in any way. So how can I make it so magento adds this altered image instead of the original one?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!!

Comment: Please add some code, I don'T understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_File](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php#L437) and look at the `prepareForCart()` method. I'm not sure specifically which events would be firing in this class, so you might just need to rewrite that method. There's a few other methods that might seem like a good target as well `_unserializeValue()` for example.